# How to split a number into its digits in scala

Tags: scala, split, numbers

The following snippet works fine to split a number into its digits, but it's too long:

```
val digits = (num toString).toList map(_.toString) map(_.toInt)
```

I maped them `toString` to get the actual value when applied `toInt` and not the `Int` value representing the `Char` returned by `toList`.

I'm new to Scala, I'm not used to the scala's expresive style.
Is there a shorter way do this.

Comment: You should use `asDigit` as Luigi mentioned, but, just so you know, you could have written your version as `num.toString.map(_.toString.toInt)`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
scala> 123.toString.map(_.asDigit)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: For negative numbers, this gives the slightly weird result of `"-123" => Seq(-1, 1, 2, 3)`.

Answer (score 5):

```
(""+123).map(_-48)
```

is I think literally the shortest, but sometimes clarity is more important.  (At least the one extra character for `'0'` instead of `48`!)

Comment: Shorter: (""+123)map(_-48)

Comment: Anyway, I don't think OP wanted the literally shortest :)

Answer (score 0):

Even you can do without changing into String:

```
def getDigits(n: Int): List[Int] = {
  def getDigits(n:Int, digits:List[Int]):List[Int]={
    if(n< 10) n::digits else getDigits(n/10, ( n % 10)::digits )
   }
  getDigits(n,Nil)
}
```

Output:

```
scala> getDigits(123)
 res55: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> getDigits(12300)
 res56: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 0, 0)

scala> getDigits(123001)
 res57: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1)
```

Comment: `List.unfold(1230)(n => Option.when(n > 0)((n%10,n/10))).reverse`